How to fix a Haraka install error on Amazon Linux?
I tried installing Haraka through npm, but it threw errors, so I tried via git and go basically the same:
 

Any help setting up an email server on AWS EC2 from scratch for a small business would be greatly appreciated.

Ran into the same issue. Following steps helped (I'm making an assumption that node and npm are installed):

Ensure make is installed (make --version)
Ensure python3 is installed (python --version)
Install development tools - sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y
Install gcc - sudo yum install gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel -y
Now you can install haraka using npm

Additional Note: Recommend installing and running these tools in sudo mode if you are just testing and experimenting as it is easier since permissions are necessary for port 25 and 587 (tls). For production always setup necessary good practice procedures, permissions, and protocols.

You didn't mention which versions of Linux, Nodejs, of Haraka that you were trying to install. If you tried to install Nodejs LTS on Amazon Linux 2, you will get errors as the glibc package that is included is too old. You should not have any problems installing Haraka on Amazon Linux 2023.
I used the following steps to install Haraka on a new instance of AL2023 on AWS EC2.
# install development tools
sudo yum install make glibc-devel gcc patch gcc-c++

# install nvm
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash
source ~/.bashrc

# install Nodejs LTS
nvm install --lts

# install Haraka
npm install -g Haraka

# create the service
haraka -i ~/haraka

# follow the configuration instructions on Github:
https://github.com/haraka/Haraka

